# Unable to access data in props

Tags: vue.js

I need to access the data passed through props to built a heatmap. The data is there but I can't use it. I want to use my `getData()` function to iterate over my data.

If I call the `"gamedata.teamA.players[0].pos[0].posY"` in the template it prints the position, but I can't use it on functions.

```
export default {
    name: "HeatMap",
    props: ["gamedata"],
    data: function() {
      return {
        teamdata: [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
        chartOptions: {
            ...
    },
    methods: {
      getData: function() {
          for(var i = 0; i < this.gamedata.teamA.players.length;i++ ){
            for(var j = 0; j < this.gamedata.teamA.players[i].pos.length;j++){
                this.teamdata[this.getPos(this.gamedata.teamA.players[i].pos[j].posY)][this.getPos(this.gamedata.teamA.players[i].pos[j].posX)]++;
            }
        }
      },
        ...,
    mounted() {
      this.getData();
      this.series = this.populate();
    }

};
```

I get the following error on the console:

```
"[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.gamedata.teamA is undefined""
```

Comment: The error state that `teamA` is undefined in your `gamedata` props. log your props in the console.

Comment: How is shaped the `gamedata` prop in the parent? It is always available or is aysnchronous? The fact that you can use `gamedata.teamA` in the template at some point does not mandatorily means that it exists during the child component creation. If  it is fetched from a backend that could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data wasn't loaded when I try to mounted(). Using a watcher before the mounted made it work.

```
watch: { gamedata(){ this.getData()} }, 
mounted() {
  this.series = this.populate();
}
```